# How to fix: Error connecting to localhost: Connection Refused in Java

Tags: java, server, localhost

I am new to java and I am working my way through a few tutorials. The tutorials don't do much for troubleshooting and I am having troulbe getting one of them to work. I am attempting to connect to my localhost server on windows 8. Here is my code:

```
import java.net.*;
public class Connect {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String server_name = "localhost";

      try {
         Socket sock = new Socket(server_name, 80);

         System.out.println("***Connect to " + server_name + " ***");

         sock.close();

      }

      catch (java.io.IOException e ) {

         System.out.println("Error connect to " + server_name + 
         ": " + e);

         return;
      }
   }
}
```

and here is my error message when i run the code:

Error connect to localhost: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: There is nothing listening on `localhost:80`

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a web site?

Comment: @tkausl so basically the code sample in the tutorial is incomplete, the book made it seem like it should say "Connected to localhost"

Comment: There should be some server (localhost) running on port 80, before you can connect to it.

Comment: It **should**, but you must run some other code that **opens** port 80, like a website

Comment: @cricket_007 i am trying to simply connect to the localhost, not really a website. the code in the book and the example output made it seem like I should get the message "Connected to localhost" .

Comment: would xampp get that done for me or do i need something more complex?

Comment: I don't know what your book says, but I doubt it fails to mention you need a server running for it to connect successfully

Comment: You can simply run a ServerSocket on port 80. Xampp is far to complex (why are you trying to use PHP to run a Java example)?  Look at SparkJava or Dropwizard for a small web server in Java, if that's what you want

Comment: Your book doesn't mention that a server needs to be running prior to sending the request?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to start my XAMPP Server prior to running the code example. Thanks all for the help!